# Filter get_page_by_path()

Tags: filters, actions

Is there a way to filter `get_page_by_path()`? I am trying to allow duplicate slugs for pages, so that two pages can have the same slug if they have different meta value for a specific meta key. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres no filter for that function. You can find the code in wp_includes/post.php (Obviously don't edit it there). [Core File](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L0)

Comment: Do you think there might me a workaround for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: That’s a hard one. The only way I can think of is to copy and rename that function in your theme, add the conditional in that function then alter the theme or whatever to use the new function. It’s an interesting case to use the same slug. Why not use one page with a query vars that decides which version to show?

Comment: I think that only works with posts, not with pages (query vars). My idea is to have two same slugs for pages if they have a different meta. I tried `pre_get_posts`, but I reverse engineered that the core ends using `get_page_by_path()` in `parse_request`

Comment: What’s the problem you’re trying to solve by having two pages with the same slug? Maybe if we zoom out we can find a solution that works.

Comment: Well there are pages which have the meta "language". Two pages can have the same slug when the meta "language" is not the same. I do not want to use taxonomies, as the choice for the meta is "hardcoded", but am open to another suggestions.